# My website appears for few mili seconds then preloader then website

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress-theming, preloader

My website preloader is not showing properly first the website appears for a few mili seconds then preloader then the website.

I am using Elementor WordPress, I have added the preloader code in my theme file editor here is the code snippet

```
"add_action('wp_footer', 'Allprocoding_Preloader');

function Allprocoding_Preloader() {
    if (!is_admin() && $GLOBALS["pagenow"] !== "wp-login.php") {
        
        $delay = 1; // seconds
        $desktop_loader = 'https://spoky.co/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/Group-1171275193-1.gif';
        $mobile_loader = 'https://spoky.co/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/mobile-.gif';
        $overlayColor = '#ffffff';
        ?>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                var preloader = document.createElement('div');
                preloader.style.position = 'fixed';
                preloader.style.top = '0';
                preloader.style.bottom = '0';
                preloader.style.left = '0';
                preloader.style.right = '0';
                preloader.style.backgroundColor = '<?php echo esc_js($overlayColor); ?>';
                preloader.style.zIndex = '100000';
                preloader.style.display = 'flex';
                preloader.style.alignItems = 'center';
                preloader.style.justifyContent = 'space-around';

                var loaderImg = document.createElement('img');
                loaderImg.src = '<?php echo esc_url($desktop_loader); ?>';
                loaderImg.alt = '';
                loaderImg.style.height = '30vw';

                preloader.appendChild(loaderImg);
                document.body.appendChild(preloader);

                document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
                var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)");

                function handleMediaChange(event) {
                    if (event.matches) {
                        loaderImg.src = '<?php echo esc_url($mobile_loader); ?>';
                        loaderImg.style.height = '20vw';
                    } else {
                        loaderImg.src = '<?php echo esc_url($desktop_loader); ?>';
                        loaderImg.style.height = '15vw';
                    }
                }

                mediaQuery.addListener(handleMediaChange);
                handleMediaChange(mediaQuery);

                window.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    // Remove the preloader after the delay
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        preloader.remove();
                        document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
                    }, <?php echo esc_js($delay * 1000); ?>);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

what to do to make the prelaoder appears perfectly fine

I have tried adding code to inline css and and preload css and JavaScript files but there is no change in the scenario. What are other possible ways to figure out this issue?

Comment: `<body style="display:none">` will smack that pony

Comment: @JaromandaX I have already tried it out but it didn't help

Comment: odd - how about adding `!important` or maybe style in the head that does `body { display:none !important }`

Comment: You are adding `Allprocoding_Preloader` to `wp_footer` action ? (that may explain website preloader is not showing properly **first the website appears** for a few mili seconds **then preloader** then the **website**) -- BTW, why not use a preloader plugin ? seems that you've created the preloader yourself

Comment: **Additional point:** One of the usual ways:  edit `header.php` file for your theme and deploy Preloader there